# 'I am looking for a baby' vs 'I am trying for a baby'

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I am non native English speaker and was being convinced by someone today that "*I am looking for a baby*" means the same as "*I am trying for a baby*"

Is that correct English?

Comment: It might be correct, but it doesn't mean the same as "I'm trying for a baby" (which means, "I'm trying to get pregnant"). "I am looking for a baby" means we have reason to believe that a certain baby exists (and we are looking for it).

Comment: @JMB Nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

It might be correct, but it doesn't mean the same as "I'm trying for a baby" (which means, "I'm trying to get pregnant"). "I am looking for a baby" means we have reason to believe that a certain baby exists (and we are looking for it)

In summary:

> To try for a baby

Is a set phrase meaning "making an effort to get pregnant".

> Look for a baby

As explained above is a case of "searching" for a baby that we have reason to believe exists. To give a concrete example:

> I'm looking for a baby with a wisp of blond hair for a TV advert.

Comment: Nobody said anything better in the 5 hours since my comment, so here is an official answer.

Comment: It's actually much better to post an answer than to answer in a comment. Then it can get both upvotes and downvotes, as well as attract focused comments of its own, in the place for them that's easiest to find. +1, by the way. :)